# MySQL DATE_ADD() when DATE is null

Tags: mysql, sql, null, dateadd

I have a DATETIME value "some_date" that can be null in my database. When I try the following query it returns nothing for those rows with date is null:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabel
WHERE DATE_ADD(some_date, INTERVAL some_seconds SECOND) < NOW()
```

Can I edit this query so that the DATE_ADD() will produce a DATE even when some_date is null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use COALESCE to convert the NULL dates to something else, for example:

```
select *
from table
where date_add(coalesce(some_date, now()), interval some_seconds second) < now()
```

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns its first non-NULL argument:

> `COALESCE(value, ...)`
>   Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

So you'd just need to decide which date you wanted to use in place of a NULL `some_date`.

---

If your replacement for a NULL `some_date` is going to be far enough into the past that the test will always pass then you could use:

```
where some_date is null
   or date_add(some_date, interval some_seconds second) < now()
```

and if it will always fail, then:

```
where some_date is not null
  and date_add(some_date, interval some_seconds second) < now()
```

Comment: FYI, I'm using COALESCE(some_date, "2000-01-01 00:00:00")

Comment: @BigJ: If a NULL is guaranteed to fail then you could use `some_date is not null and date_add(some_date, ....` instead; if it will always pass then `some_date is null or date_add(some_date, ...`. That would get around glglgl's index issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a little clearer to use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabel
WHERE some_date IS NULL OR DATE_ADD(some_date, INTERVAL some_seconds SECOND) < NOW()
```

Comment: It tested it, it works. But why? What are you saying at the WHERE condition?

Comment: The WHERE clause is true if some_date has not been set (null) or if it is set, when it plus some seconds is less than the current time.